# How do i determine the value of $l$ and $M$ of the defined ellipse in the below problem?

Tags: education, conic-sections

let an ellipse defined with the following  equation :$$ly²+3x²=M $$ and it's center is the origine and   intersect with the parobola which is defined with this equation :$$x²+\sqrt{3}y-3=0$$

**My Question here  :** How do i determine the value of $l$ and $M$ where it's periphery is $14\pi$ ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Not enough information: do we know *how* (many times) the ellipse intersects the parabola?  What is the periphery of the ellipse?  Arc length of boundary?

Comment: The exact perimeter of an ellipse cannot be calculated exactly from the axes.  It is about $\pi(a+b)$ where $a$ is the semimajor axis and $b$ is the semiminor axis.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference)